# Assigning user role on signup failing, using RBAC in Yii2

Tags: yii2, rbac

I am working on a code whereby the admin is the one to signup users and assign roles to them. I have managed to come up with the code to collect form data, signup users in the database, but the final step of calling the DbManager for assigning roles is failing. My codes are shown below;

Here is the `actionCreate()` function:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Staff();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->signup()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is the signup function of the model `Staff()`

```
public function signup()
{
    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return null;
    }

    $user = new Admin();
    $user->username = $this->username;
    $user->email = $this->email;
    $user->setPassword($this->password);
    $user->generateAuthKey();
    $user->first_name = $this->first_name;
    $user->last_name = $this->last_name;
    $user->mobile = $this->mobile;
    $user->station_id = $this->station_id;

    if($user->save()) {
        $p_key = $user->getPrimaryKey();

        $r=new DbManager;
        // $r->init();
        if($this->role == 1) {
            $role = 'courier';
            $r->assign($role, $p_key);   //(userId, role)
        }
        else if($this->role == 2) {
            $role = 'tickets_officer';
            $r->assign($role, $p_key);   //(userId, role)
        }
        else if($this->role == 3) {
            $role = 'supervisor';
            $r->assign($role, $p_key);   //(userId, role)
        }

    }

    return $p_key;
}
```

The error that I am getting is this:
 `PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException`

`Trying to get property of non-object`

```
public function assign($role, $userId)
{
    $assignment = new Assignment([
        'userId' => $userId,
        'roleName' => $role->name,
        'createdAt' => time(),
    ]);

    $this->db->createCommand()
        ->insert($this->assignmentTable, [
            'user_id' => $assignment->userId,
            'item_name' => $assignment->roleName,
            'created_at' => $assignment->createdAt,
        ])->execute();
```

In the above error code, the line with `'roleName' => $role->name,` is underlined meaning that is where the problem is.

Remember I am getting my roles using a dropdown menu where the sellections are either 1, 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should define `authManager` component instead of using DbManager class directly.

The logic of `assign()` was changed. In latest versions it takes Role object instead of string.

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

// You should previously init it once, e.c. in migration, like this: $auth->createRole('courier');
$courier = $auth->getRole('courier');
$auth->assign($courier, $p_key);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks so much dude. You are a great savior. It worked just like that.  There is no such documentation online. I guess I have been following the outdated docs. Thanks once again.